# How to POST Data to an API in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-router

My goal is to be able to **POST** the data in my body and the one a user has input on the **FORM**. When a user clicks submit the data must be sent and I would like to display, **Loading**, and then the **Response** from the **Server** when the post has been made. With some error handling also.

I have tried using **Axios** and simple POST with error handling, but with no luck.

When I console Results. I see the Server response. But I only want the data to be send only when I click the Submit Button. Not when I load the page.

Below is the example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
  Link,
  generatePath,
} from "react-router-dom";

function Checkout({ cart, setCart, handleChange, countCartItem }) {
  const token = "3bb990f1-5fbe-39bf-a320-8ad11b4bc95c";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        transactionReference: "string",
        paymentMethod: "CreditCard",
        checkoutOrderUrl: "http://www.test.com/",
        user: {
          name: "string",
          msisdn: "+27610983142",
          email: "test@test.com",
        },
        payementMethodDetail: {
          RedirectUrl: "http://www.test.com",
          PurchaseEventWebhookUrl: "http://www.test.com",
        },
        bundle: [
          {
            productCode: "317",
            amount: 50,
            currencyCode: "ZAR",
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
      }),
    };
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResult(json));
  }, []);

  console.log(result);

  const price = cart.reduce(
    (total, item) => total + item.amount * item.FaceValue,
    0
  );

  const orderTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => +price + +item.Vat, 0);

  const vat = cart.reduce((total, item) => item.Vat, 12);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, surname, cellphone, email } = e.target.elements;

    const data = {
      name: name.value,
      surname: surname.value,
      cellphone: cellphone.value,
      email: email.value,
      orderTotal,
      cart,
    };

    console.log(data);
  }

  console.log();

  return (
    <>
      <div class="container-fluid" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 px-5">
            <article>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 p-5">
                  <div className="py-4">
                    <Link to="/cart">
                      <span style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 700 }}>
                        <span>
                          <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-short"></i>
                        </span>
                        Back to Cart
                      </span>
                    </Link>

                    <br />
                    <span style={{ fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 700 }}>
                      Shipping Information
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <div style={{ margin: "100px 290px" }}>
                    <h2
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: 700,
                        width: "285px",
                        lineHeight: "23px",
                        paddingBottom: 16,
                      }}
                    >
                      Please provide your details to continue to payment
                    </h2>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <label for="staticEmail" className="col col-form-label">
                        First Name
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Your name"
                        id="name"
                      />
                      <label
                        for="staticEmail"
                        className="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        Surname
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Surname"
                        id="surname"
                      />
                      <label
                        for="staticEmail"
                        className="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        Cellphone
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Cellphone"
                        id="cellphone"
                      />
                      <label
                        for="staticEmail"
                        className="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        Email
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        id="email"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <input
                        style={{
                          width: "100%",
                          height: 48,
                          fontWeight: 700,
                          borderRadius: 8,
                          border: "solid #97E128 1px",
                          padding: "auto",
                          backgroundColor: "#97E128",
                        }}
                        type="submit"
                        value="Confirm to payment"
                      />
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                class="row position-fixed fixed-bottom"
                style={{ display: "contents" }}
              >
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the API from your `handleSubmit` function instead of `useEffect`. `useEffect` is called when page load and on rerender.
Just move your code from useEffect to function and call that function from your `handleSubmit` with user entered form data.

Comment: An example would be great

Answer (score 0):

Move code from `useEffect` to `handleSubmit`. Read how the `useEffect` works because you don't understand it. Make variable `isLoading` and make it false on default. Make variable `responseData` and set it to null on default. In jsx make conditional rendering like `{isLoading && <Loading_component>}`. In jsx make conditional rendering like `{responseData && {responseData}}` to render the response (I don't know how your response is formatted, you need to modify what I wrote). In handleSubmit before fetch set `isLoading to true` and inside the fetch in .then set it to `false` and next to it (still inside .then) set your `responseData to response.data`. After .then make `.catch` and inside it handle your errors from api if there are some.

Comment: An example would be great